# missing assemblies Xamarin when creating new project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new in xamarin.forms, i want to create a simple project using xamarin.forms with VS2017, but i got this error when i create a new project (cross-platform/mobile app (xamarin.forms) / Blank App)

[image]

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App3
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the version 3.0 of xamarin.forms and visual studio 2017

i want to understand the error.

Comment: Clean and rebuild 10 times 

Comment: @François dosen't work, i got the same error when i want to clean or rebuild the solution

Comment: right click your solution and try to restore the nuget packages.

Comment: i think i shoul install .net 4.7 framework, but it not shown at the list, i have only .net 4.6 or above

Comment: You don't need .net framework. Your forms project should be .net standard.

Comment: your used Windows must be at least Windows 10 v1709 and the Min/Target Version for possible UWP project and the shared project type must be .net standard 2.0.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I just updated my Windows 10 and it worked